# Car codes changing

Tags: pontiac, grand-prix

I have a 2008 Pontiac Grand Prix. I had a code P071 I replace the 02 upstream and now I have P0420 I have read many forums about this issue and it seems like a common problem for this vehicle ... know has a firm answer to what can fix this issue. Help please

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Curious why you didn't change out the downstream O2 when you did the upstream?

Comment: Also, what is the exact code for the first code ... P071 is not a code as it needs to be five characters long (like the P0420).